# When a member joins a server, i want to ping them then delete it (JS)

Tags: discord, discord.js

I would like to ping a user in a channel (to alert them to it) then delete the message.

I have seen this on many large discord servers, they use custom bots for it so I think it wouldn't be too hard!

Comment: Well, what do you need help with? Do you get any errors? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask <- please read this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your `guildMemberAdd` event get, the channel you want to send the ping in, then do `` channel.send(`${member.user}`) ``.

Here, `member` is the argument you gave to the callback function in the event. `member.user` will ping them in that channel.

`send()` method returns the message you sent as a promise, which means you can just catch that message and delete it like this: `send().then(message => message.delete())`.

You can provide timeout as an optional parameter to the `delete()` method if you want to delete the message after a specific period of time and not instantly. This is what the whole code will look like:

```
bot.on('guildMemberAdd', (member) => {
    const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.get('id');  // get the channel using the id
    channel.send(`${member.user}`)
        .then(message => message.delete());
}
```